# Не работает вход через google в webview приложение

Tags: java, android

Подскажите пожалуйста как решить проблему? В простом Webview приложении на сайте не работает вход с помощью Google.

Ошибка которую выдает при попытке входа через приложение!

```
Ошибка 403: disallowed_useragent
Google can’t sign you in safely inside this app. You can use Google sign-in by visiting this app’s website in a browser like Safari or Chrome.
```

MainActivity.java

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    WebView webView;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        webView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webview);

        // Force links and redirects to open in the WebView instead of in a browser
        webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {

            @Override
            public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
                if (url == null || url.startsWith("http://") || url.startsWith("https://")) return false;

                try {
                    Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(url));
                    view.getContext().startActivity(intent);
                    return true;
                } catch (Exception e) {

                    return true;
                }
            }
        });

        // Enable Javascript
        WebSettings webSettings = webView.getSettings();
        webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);

        // Use remote resource
        webView.loadUrl("http://jaliwood.kg/");

    }

    @Override
    public void onBackPressed(){
        if(webView.canGoBack()) {
            webView.goBack();
        }
        else{
            super.onBackPressed();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Судя по всему не хватает тега android. Обычные джависты, кто под андроид не пишет, вам с этим вопросом вряд ли помогут.

Comment: желательно приложить какой-то код который у вас используется)

Comment: @Andrew Код добавил